# Calling upon shell scripts / . jar files from within a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I have a bash script which has some .sh files within it, the .sh files contain instructions to copy from and execute a .jar file which is also called upon at the beginning of the script. I can't seem to successfully execute the .sh files but the .jar file at the beginning executes without any issues. Here is what I mean: `java -jar energyapp-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar &`This is at the beginning, and has no problem executing. Then later in the script I have this: `./mAhSim.sh &` `sh ./solarsim.sh &` sh `./batterysim.sh &`. These have instructions as follows:

```
java -cp energyapp-simulators-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com..xml.SolarSimulator'
```

but when I execute it, it fires up the browser as expected, but I get an error reading "Error retrieving events & data"

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks folks

Comment: Are the .sh-scripts indeed in the current directory? What happens if you do a `bash mahSim.sh` by hand?  Does it provide the required data, probably in a file, at the right location? same for the other scripts. Or is it just that the scripts need to create the data before you start the jave application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use source command to execute another shell script within the same folder.
Use this:

```
source filename.sh
```

Or you can use the alias:

```
. filename.sh
```

Also make sure all your files are executable.
So you can do:

```
source mAhSim.sh && source solarsim.sh && source batterysim.sh
```

Comment: I've seemed to have narrowed down the problem. The .sh files are executing fine now, but the Java .jar file at the beginning of the script wont fire up the data to the browser unless it has "gnome-terminal --command=' jar file '. Otherwise it gives me the cannot display data error. Any idea for a workaround without it firing up a terminal after execution?